On the role of Homogeneity constraints
I refer here to the following paper by ECB: "What caused the euro area post-pandemic inflation?" I attach an equation about short term inflation expectations. What is unclear to me is the final statement into the round brackets. My guess is that one should simply compute the values of $\pi_t^{e1}$ at $t+1$, $t+2$ etc to enlight the role of the homogeneity constraint but I do not see it.
Could someone give me some hint?
